# Does Microsoft Bot Framework Require LUIS For NLU?

Tags: rasa, azure-language-understanding

In other words, can I use another engine like RASA rather than LUIS?

Answer (score 1):

> Does Microsoft Bot Framework Require LUIS For NLU?

No

> In other words, can I use another engine like RASA rather than LUIS?

Yes

While bots have certain structure, in the end, they are just another ASP.NET application. You can extend and customize them to do what you wish. That being said; there is no built-in scaffolding for other NLU like RASA, etc.

I would suggest taking a look at the [Core bot sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot), which does use LUIS. As well as the [SDK itself](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet) (linking dotnet, as I assuming you're using that). But you can see how that is done and give you a starting point.

I would recommend familiarizing yourself with the SDK and documentation so you know what and where the built in functions are and how they handle interaction with the users and connector. Including the implementation of middleware.

If you are using Composer instead of the SDK, you could make calls to other NLPs, but it won't be as integral as with LUIS. You can make specific calls, but there you won't easily be able to just replace LUIS for something else.